# Building projects depending on profile in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project environment. I want something like, if from command line 'gradle clean -PsubProj build' is fired from root project directory, only 'subProj' is built.
For 'gradle clean -Pdev build' or 'gradle clean build' all other sub projects except 'subProj' should be built.
I tried doing the following in settings.gradle:

```
if (rootProject.hasProperty('subProj')) {
    include "subProj"
}else{
   include "subProj1", "subProj2", "subProj3"
}
```

But its not working.

Observed behavior:
In any case, only projects in 'else' part is being built, "subProj" is never picked up.

What am I missing. TIA.

Comment: Any error message of any kind ? What is the observed behavior ?

Comment: No error message. "subProj" is never picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `rootProject`

```
if (hasProperty('subProj')) {
    include "subProj"
} else {
   include "subProj1", "subProj2", "subProj3"
}
```